# Too much recursion

Tags: javascript, dom, recursion

I'm using JS on firefox 4 and get the "too much recursion error" for the following code:

```
  extractText: function(domObj) {
    if (domObj == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
        var acc = "";
        if (domObj.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            acc += domObj.nodeValue;
        }
        if (domObj.hasChildNodes()) {   
            var children = currentObj.childNodes;
            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                acc += sui.extractText(children[i]);
            }
        }
        return acc;
    }
  }
};
```

Anyone?

Comment: Where are `currentObj` and `sui` defined?

Comment: This is not valid Javascript. Please post an actual testcase.

Comment: currentObj was my problem, wrong variable - stupid me :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think that this line:

```
        var children = currentObj.childNodes;
```

should be:

```
        var children = domObj.childNodes;
```

It looks to me as if your reference to "currentObj" is starting over at the top instead of descending from the element under examination. It's hard to tell of course because you didn't include the relevant definition or initialization of "currentObj".

Comment: hey, that was correct! Thanks.  However no I have a different problem and get things that are NOT text, like:   #hdr-editions a { text-decoration:none; }
#cnn_hdr-editionS { text-align:left;clear:both; }                            Anyone?
#cnn_hdr-editionS a { text-decoration:none;font-size:10px;top:7px;line-height:12px;font-weight:bold; }
#hdr-prompt-text b { display:inline-block;margin:0 0 0 20px; }
#hdr-editions li { padding:0 10px; }

#hdr-editions ul li.no-pad-left span { font-size:12px; }
.hdr-arrow-intl, .hdr-arrow-us, .hdr-arrow-us2 { left:148px; }
.hdr-arrow-us2 { left:180px; }

Comment: @eve this is another question now... Do not ask in comments. But i'm sure it is because there are inline styles in the document... Hard to tell as you did not put the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try an iterative approach instead of recursion:

```
extractText: function(domObj) {
    if (!(domObj instanceof Node)) return null;
    var stack = [domObj], node, tf = [];
    while (stack.length > 0) {
         node = stack.pop();
         switch (node.nodeType) {
         case Node.TEXT_NODE:
             tf.push(node.nodeValue);
             break;
         case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
             for (var i=node.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--)
                 stack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
             break;
         }
    }
    return tf.join("");
}
```

This algorithm implements a [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) using a stack for the nodes that still must be visited. The first item on the stack is `domObj` if it’s a [*Node* instance](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247). Then for each node on the stack: if it is a [*Text* node](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772), its value is added to the text fragments array `tf`; if it’s an [*Element* node](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614), its child nodes are put on the stack in reverse order so that the first child is on top of the stack. These steps are repeated until the stack is empty. At the end, the text fragments in `tf` are put together using the array’s `join` method.